# MySql database excludes A.M, P.M, from datetime, timestamp, time, PHP, SQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time, timestamp

I have three data types in my database. Datetime, timestamp, and time. I get the time using the date function and tried to insert it into the database under all three columns, but all three columns rejected the A.M, P.M part of the date function. I don't understand why. I need the A.M, P.M part of the date function to be also inserted, so I can sort the data in my database more efficiently by time. Is there another column that can store the A.M, P.M part of the date, or is there a workaround this? Thanks.

```
$time = date('h:i:s A');
//insert $time into all three columns into the database
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The workaround is to use the `hours` value as 24 hour clock. To represent **`'3:45:56 PM`'**, insert to the database column a string value **`'15:45:56'`**.

Otherwise, you can use the **`STR_TO_DATE`** function to convert the string into a valid `TIME` value.

```
 INSERT INTO mytable (mycol) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('3:45:56 PM','%h:%i:%s %p'))
```

---

To retrieve a `TIME` value from a database column, formatted as 12 hour clock with AM/PM.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(mytimecol,'%h:%i:%s %p') AS mytimestr FROM ...
```

References:

[**`STR_TO_DATE`** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

[**`DATE_FORMAT`** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: Dates and times are stored in [ISO8601 Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and with good reason. AM/PM is a *presentation* problem, not a data concern.

Comment: Is that the only workaround? That would mean that when we get the data from the database, the time will the in 24 hour format too, and if we want to convert it back into the 12 hour format, we would have to do it row by row after taking the data from the database, which makes it a lot more complicated then it needs to be.

Comment: @frosty: The `DATE_FORMAT` function is available to format a `TIME` value into a string representation of your choosing, including 12 hour clock and AM/PM indicator.  `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(mytimecol,'%h:%i:%s %p') AS mytimestr FROM ...`.  Representing a `TIME` value in 12-hour clock with AM/PM isn't really that complicated.

Comment: If the column type is time, when you insert the data into the database with the column time, doesn't it auto-convert the string that you got from the date function into a time value?

Comment: @frosty: yes, MySQL does "auto-convert" the string value, but it does that conversion based on MySQL rules. MySQL expects datetime strings to be in format `'2015-07-21 16:34:25'`. If you are going to supply a different format, you need to tell MySQL what that format is, using the `STR_TO_DATE` function.

Comment: Ah. I see. Insert the time in 24 hour format, and when you get it out, use the date_format to show the A.M, P.M in the 12 hour format. That actually works very, very well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change the column data type as Varchar(20)
and insert $time = date('h:i:s A'); into database.

**Get from DB:-**

while fetching this column from database u can use 
date('h:i:s A',strtotime($fetched_datetime_from_db)).

Enjoy!!