# Laravel with mysql how to retrieve records by time

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am using laravel 5.1 with mysql to my projects. In my project requirement I need to show records which are in am(ante meridiem) for every day or pm(post meridiem) for every day. How can I build query for Am Pm check on created_at.

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549767/mysql-database-excludes-a-m-p-m-from-datetime-timestamp-time-php-sql answer

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the value of `created_at` to time to check if it is before or after 12:00.

```
WHERE TIME(created_at) < '12:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Where between would probably be better for you

```
   Model::whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->get()
```

Just change the from and to values for your start and end times.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your datetime is like this - "24 Aug 2017 07:15 am"
Then this is the way to retrive record -

```
$res = User::where('created_at',date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($request->created_at)))->get(); 
// date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($request->created_at)) convert your date into required format to compare with db's created_at
```

Hope this will help you.